# asp.net/ sql how can i save the text in Server.GetLastError() to DB when it has single quotes inside the string?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i have the below code and find that the text value represented in `Server.GetLastError`
contains single quotes and breaks my SQL insert code.

```
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

StringBuilder theBody = new StringBuilder();        
theBody.Append("Error Message: " + ex.ToString() + "\n");

Server.ClearError();

try
    {
        string sSQL = "INSERT INTO PMISwebErr VALUES ('" + theBody.ToString() + "', GETDATE())";

        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = STAR.Global.GetConnection())
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sSQL, con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exe) {
        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx?Err="+ exe.Message.ToString() );
    }
```

Comment: using your application, enter and save this value: `1',GETDATE());drop table PMISwebErr--` and see what happens when you concatenate strings containing user input to build a sql command.

Comment: See "little Bobby Tables" - http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    string sSQL = "INSERT INTO PMISwebErr VALUES (@errVal, GETDATE())";

    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = STAR.Global.GetConnection())
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sSQL, con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@errVal", theBody.ToString() );
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```

**You should always use parameters in your SQL Statements.**  Not only does it handle cases such as strings with single-quotes, but it helps to protect you against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: +1, just thought I'd highlight a very important statement you made.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wonderful world of SQL Injection attacks...

Option 1: search and replace theBody.ToString(), replacing "'" with "''"

Option 2: [rewrite your SQL command to use parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

And, just because, you need to [check this link](http://xkcd.com/327/) too.